# recursion too slow with ruby

Tags: ruby, recursion

i'm newbie in programming. i learn ruby and i'm stuck with a hackerearth problem : not the whole solution but only with speed of my program...
the problem is to place a n(umber) of queens on a board n*n with a recursion.
here is the solution i submitted :

```
def is_attacked(x,y,n,chess_board)  
    return true if chess_board[x].include?(1)
    sum=x+y
    diff=x-y
    p=0 
    while p<=n-1
        return true if p!=x && chess_board[p][y]==1
        q=0

        while q<=n-1
            (((p+q==sum)||(p-q==diff)) && chess_board[p][q]==1) ? (return true) : q+=1
        end
    p+=1 
   end
   return false
end

def n_Queens(n,n_fix,chess_board)
    return true if n==0
    i=0 
    while i<=n_fix-1
        j=0
        while j<=n_fix-1
            if is_attacked(i,j,n_fix,chess_board)
                j+=1
                next
            else
                chess_board[i][j]=1
                n_Queens(n-1,n_fix,chess_board) ? (return true) : chess_board[i][j]=0
            end
            j+=1
        end
        i+=1
    end
    return false
end

n=gets.chomp.to_i
n_fix=n
chess_board=Array.new(n) {Array.new(n,0)}
if n_Queens(n,n_fix,chess_board)
    chess_board.each do |line|
        puts line.join(" ")
    end
else
    puts "Not possible"
end
```

I used while instead of each because i read it was a little bit faster but...
If you can help, i will appreciate and certainly put my skills at a better level.
thanks

Comment: I don't know Ruby, but are you sure your recursive solution isn't creating object copies every recurse? That'll be expensive.

Comment: the problem in hackerearth compiler is with the last input : 10.

Comment: It does not look like you used all possible shortcuts. The N-Queen problem will have 1 queen per column. So the usual solution to the problem involves something like ``queen[col] is the row of the queen on the col-th column. Then you recurse over the columns and "try" rows on each column until you find a configuration which is a solution (in depth 8)`` I cannot really see if your code works that way or tries something else.

Comment: Recursion is slow itself in Ruby or other language. All the use cases (or most of them) is possible to refactor without recursion and it probably is what you need to do.

Comment: Ruby is not a language you use for running something quickly.  Write it in C if you care about speed.

Comment: @VAD daring theory. There is something called tailcalls, you know... and it is just as efficient as looping. Also, try to get some imperative solution to run on multiple cores ;)

Answer (score 1):

Now we are all proud owners of 64 bit unsigned integers and 64 bit operating systems, N > 8 is really annoying. Maybe I should wait till I am on x128 platforms and F# has a uint128 and then answer the question...

Joking aside. Once you write an optimized program, the straightforward approach does not always make the cut. You can save time pre-computing stuff and creating lookup tables and as such reduce the time the inner loop/recursion requires.

The code below loads (and pre-computes the look up tables) in around 8ms and solves the nqueens for N=8 in around 2ms on my machine. And it is a .NET language, not some native code. And it is run in the fsi (interactive shell).

It uses bitboards (which work well up to N=8 with a uint64).

The trick is that if you placed k queens on k columns, you can filter in the (k+1) recursion for rows which are not threatened by the previously positioned k queens. Thus, the deeper you get, the fewer rows you have to actually consider in your search (improving algorithmic complexity somewhat).

For N > 8, you could try to do the same and use as board 2 uint64 values (10*10 = 100 < 128). Just like in the old chess programming days on 32 bit machines, people used 2 uint32 for bit boards...

> nqueens 8;;
>   Real: 00:00:00.002, CPU: 00:00:00.000, GC gen0: 0, gen1: 0, gen2: 0
>   val it : int [] option = Some [|0; 4; 7; 5; 2; 6; 1; 3|]

Now, I have no idea how fast Ruby is compared to F#, but I doubt you could not come up with a solution meeting the timing requirements of that hacker site, even if you need something less efficient than the bit boards my code uses.

So, the code below will maybe give you ideas where to start with optimizing your Ruby code. (Sorry - I know nothing about Ruby...)

```ml
let binary (v : uint64) (tw : System.IO.TextWriter)  =
    let mask : uint64 = 0x1UL <<< 63
    let rec printDigit m c =
        if c % 8 = 0 then tw.WriteLine()
        match m with
        | 0UL -> ()
        | _ -> 
            if m &&& v <> 0UL then
                tw.Write("1")
            else 
                tw.Write("0")
            printDigit (m >>> 1) (c+1)
    printDigit mask 0

let showMask (m : uint64) =
    printfn "%t" (binary m)

let squareIndexBig n col row = row * n + col

let squareIndex col row = row * 8 + col

let squareMaskBig n col row =
    bigint.One <<< squareIndexBig n col row

let squareMask col row = 1UL <<< squareIndex col row

let diagMovesBig n col row =
    let mutable c = col
    let mutable r = row
    let mutable b = bigint.Zero
    while c > -1 && row > -1 do
        b <- b ||| squareMaskBig n c r
        c <- c - 1
        r <- r - 1
    c <- col
    r <- row
    while c < n && r < n do
        b <- b ||| squareMaskBig n c r
        c <- c + 1
        r <- r + 1
    c <- col
    r <- row
    while c > -1 && r < n do
        b <- b ||| squareMaskBig n c r
        c <- c - 1
        r <- r + 1
    c <- col
    r <- row
    while c < n && r > -1 do
        b <- b ||| squareMaskBig n c r
        c <- c + 1
        r <- r - 1
    b

let diagMoves col row =
    let mutable c = col
    let mutable r = row
    let mutable b = 0UL
    while c > -1 && row > -1 do
        b <- b ||| squareMask c r
        c <- c - 1
        r <- r - 1
    c <- col
    r <- row
    while c < 8 && r < 8 do
        b <- b ||| squareMask c r
        c <- c + 1
        r <- r + 1
    c <- col
    r <- row
    while c > -1 && r < 8 do
        b <- b ||| squareMask c r
        c <- c - 1
        r <- r + 1
    c <- col
    r <- row
    while c < 8 && r > -1 do
        b <- b ||| squareMask c r
        c <- c + 1
        r <- r - 1
    b

let nlowerbits n =
    let mutable v  = 0x01UL
    for i in [1..n] do
        v <- (v <<< 1) ||| 1UL
    bigint v

let nbitswideOne n =
    let mutable v  = bigint.One
    for i in [1..n] do
        v <- (v <<< n) ||| bigint.One
    v


let row0CodeBig n = 
    [|
        for r in 0..n-1 do
            yield (nlowerbits n) <<< (n * r)
    |]


let row0Code = 
    [|
        for r in 0..7 do
            yield 0b11111111UL <<< (8 * r)
    |]

let col0CodeBig n =
    [|
        for c in 0..n-1 do
            yield nbitswideOne n <<< c
    |]

let col0Code = 
    [|
        for c in 0..7 do
            yield 0b0000000100000001000000010000000100000001000000010000000100000001UL <<< c
    |]

let diagCodeBig n =
    [|
        for col in 0..n-1 do
            yield 
                [|
                    for row in 0..n-1 do
                        yield diagMovesBig n col row
                |]
    |]


let diagCode = 
    [|
        for col in 0..7 do
            yield 
                [|
                    for row in 0..7 do
                        yield diagMoves col row
                |]
    |]

let placeQueenBig n col row =
    (row0CodeBig n).[row] ||| (col0CodeBig n).[col] ||| (diagCodeBig n).[col].[row]

let placeQueen col row =
    row0Code.[row] ||| (col0Code.[col]) ||| (diagCode.[col].[row])

let squareSafeBig n board col row =
    bigint.Zero = (board &&& squareMaskBig n col row)

let squareSafe board col row =
    0UL = (board &&& squareMask col row)

let nqueensBig n =
    let queenRows : int[] = Array.zeroCreate n
    let assign col row = queenRows.[col] <- row

    let rec place board col =
        //showMask board
        match col with
        | x when x = n -> true
        | _ ->
            [0..n-1]
            |> List.filter (fun row -> squareSafeBig n board col row)
            |> List.tryFind (fun row -> place (board ||| placeQueenBig n col row) (col+1))
            |> fun row -> 
                    match row with
                    | None -> false
                    | Some r ->
                        assign col r
                        true

    if place (bigint.Zero) 0
    then
        Some queenRows
    else
        None


let nqueens n =
    let queenRows : int[] = Array.zeroCreate n
    let assign col row = queenRows.[col] <- row

    let rec place board col =
        //showMask board
        match col with
        | x when x = n -> true
        | _ ->
            [0..n-1]
            |> List.filter (fun row -> squareSafe board col row)
            |> List.tryFind (fun row -> place (board ||| placeQueen col row) (col+1))
            |> fun row -> 
                    match row with
                    | None -> false
                    | Some r ->
                        assign col r
                        true

    if place 0UL 0
    then
        Some queenRows
    else
        None
```

**Update**

Using the `System.Math.BigInteger` also known as `bigint` in F#, I extended the code with a `nqueensBig n` function which also solves problems for N > 8.
Performance not as blazing as the `nqueens n` and not heap-operation free but I think still sufficiently fast.

> nqueensBig 10;;
>   Real: 00:00:00.071, CPU: 00:00:00.078, GC gen0: 10, gen1: 1, gen2: 0
>   val it : int [] option = Some [|0; 2; 5; 7; 9; 4; 8; 1; 3; 6|]
>
> nqueensBig 13;;
>   Real: 00:00:00.167, CPU: 00:00:00.171, GC gen0: 23, gen1: 0, gen2: 0
>   val it : int [] option = Some [|0; 2; 4; 1; 8; 11; 9; 12; 3; 5; 7; 10; 6|]

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! I will look in the direction you pointed.

Comment: i managed to spare a lot of time and succeed the challenge by recording in an array the number of the column occupied by the queen just set in the new position : a shortcut i did not use in my first solution.